# the meaning of "take on"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have refer to the dictionary. It has the meaning of "take the responsibility of .."
The background is:
the scientist has invented an kind of technique. He can translating the painting into virtual world just like creating the Second Life Avatar. By doing this he can analyse whether the light in the painting is natural or created by the studio. I think this sentence means he begin to analyse the paint<> using this kind of technology.
and in this sentence ， “the scientist has taken on "Las Meninas"by Velazquez, possibly the greatest picture ever made”, I think it can be translated to"decide to do "better. Because if the work is not assigned by others ,it should not be equals as"undertake".

what do you think of it? "take the responsibility "or "decide to do"?

Comment: Not enough context. Please add more of the surrounding sentences.

Comment: now what sbout it?

Comment: "Take on" = he will challenge himself by using his technique on a difficult painting.

Comment: sometimes i think the translation is too flexiable to get command of  ... so the phrase  take on has the meaning of "challenge oneself"?

Comment: can you help me about it , please?

Comment: I disagree when you say "Because if the work is not assigned by others ,it should not be equals as 'undertake'" - "to undertake" a task does not require that it be assigned by someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We **take on** a challenge.  We **take** a challenge **on**.

> Jonas Salk took on the challenge of finding a polio vaccine.

We **take on** an adversary. We take an adversary **on**.

> He took on the bully who had been making school unbearable.

We **take on** a responsibility or task. We **take** a responsibility or task **on**.

> He took on the responsibility of coaching the team.
>
> He took on the task of  fixing the roof.

**take on** is a so-called "phrasal verb".

It means "to face, to address (as a problem that needs solving or situation that needs to be improved or remedied or handled or as a task to be seen to completion)"

Comment: thanks for your answer .so the meaning of "take the responsibility of " and"to face or to address " is different, right?

Comment: You can also take on a responsibility.  I've added an example.

Comment: take a task on means "begin to do it" or"begin to undertake the ability of doing it" which translation is better?

Comment: To commit oneself to it.